# How to capture point click event in Highchart Angular when using boost module

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have a line chart displaying a large dataset with multiple series, so I have enabled the boost module for performance.

I know that the boost module disables data-point click events but I still require that functionality. There is a workaround described [in the git issue here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14067) for vanilla JS.

But does anyone know how to workaround this limitation in Angular / Typescript?

Using highcharts 10.2.0 and highcharts-angular 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the same workaround, by using type assertion: `this.series as any`.

```
   plotOptions: {
      line: {
        point: {
          events: {
            click: function () {
              console.log(this);
            },
            mouseOver: function () {
              if ((this.series as any).halo) {
                (this.series as any).halo
                  .attr({
                    class: 'highcharts-tracker',
                  })
                  .toFront();
              }
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }
```

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-sta2dj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts